# Testing End of Token

Tags: c, string, validation, token, tokenize

I'm trying to do a simple thing but can't figure it out. I am tokenizing data from a .csv file and storing it in a structure however I'm trying to validate the data using a function that returns TRUE or FALSE weather it is valid input or not.

basically i want this function to return TRUE if the datapos = 1 and there is no numbers in the token. my code so far is....

ps: the printf() is just there for debugging purposes.

```
int validCustData(int datapos, char *token) {

   int valid = FALSE;
   int pos;

   switch (datapos) {

      case 1:
         pos = 0;

         while (pos < SURNAME_MAX) {
            printf("checking char %c\n", token[pos]);

            if (isdigit(token[pos])) {
               break;
            }
            if (token[pos] == '\0') {
               valid = TRUE;
               break;
            }
            pos = pos + 1;
         }
         break;


    }

   return valid;
}
```

It seems to never enter the statement 'if (token[pos] == '\0')' is this not the character that ends a token? if not which one dictates the end of a token? or how else can I achieve this effect? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after cleaning up random bits of code it is now working, I have no idea why it wasn't before, it seemed to just be buffering error. but this function with no changes at all is now working. sorry for the waste of time.